# Can't access methods in Entity class

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, persistence

Following Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities) on creating backends for mobile applications i was able to create Entities for my project.In the tutorial it says to `"Generate Endpoint class for each Entity class"` and then `"Generate a Cloud Endpoint client Library for the App Engine project by right-clicking the App Engine project, and selecting Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Client"`. I followed these instructions to the latter.In my `Employee` Entity class, i have a method

```
public void addSales(Sales sale) {
    getSales().add(sale);
}
```

But when i try to access this method in my activity, it says `"The method addSales() is undefined for the type Employee"`.Instead i am given `setSales()` which i didn't declare anywhere.Am really confused as to why this is happening.